# Javascript function is missing in index.html when page initially loads in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have the following script in index.html:

```
    <script>
    function scrollToSelectedRow(gridSelector) {
        var gridWrapper = document.querySelector(gridSelector);
        if (gridWrapper) {
            var selectedRow = gridWrapper.querySelector("tr.k-selected");
            if (selectedRow) {
                selectedRow.scrollIntoView();
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I call this function in my razor page:

```
await JsInterop.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToSelectedRow", ".vehicle-selector-grid");
```

When I launch the application, I get an error that the javascript function was not found. When I look at index.html, all my other scripts are there but the new one I added was missing. I've tried cleaning and building my solution, and clearing the site data but the same issue occurs. Only when I hard refresh the page does it actually show up. What can be going on?